# 'pip2' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script on my windows 10 computer using Python 2.7.

I run the ff command:

```
python boxtool.py
```

Then I got the ff errors:

```
'pip2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'pip2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File boxtool.py", line 14, in <module>
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
ImportError: No module named requests.exceptions
```

Looking at the code, here are the codes in line 14:

```
except ImportError:
    os.system("pip2 install requests")
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from mechanize import Browser
```

I am new in Python. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Python 2 is old & unsupported, why not use python 3?

Comment: The program I am running at is made in Python2 I guess.

Comment: Try `os.system("pip install requests")` (Check if pip executable is on your PATH). Also, I know you can install your dependencies from within the script, but I really don't get this approach. Use requirements.txt instead

Answer (score 1):

Download the `get-pip.py` file: get-pip.py on [pypa.io](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Then install it using python

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I downloaded the file and place it inside the folder where the program is sitting. Then I tried running that. I got this error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip`